# I want to change the height of the appbar using the value of json style file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `app_bar_base.dart` file where i have an AppBar.

```
class AppBarBase extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  late double appBarHeight = LoadAppStyle().loadAppStyle();


  AppBarBase({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar();
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(appBarHeight);
}
```

I am calling the method `LoadAppStyle().loadAppStyle()` from the file `load_app_style`:

```
class LoadAppStyle {
  loadAppStyle() async {
    String jsonData =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config/app_style.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    var getHeight = double.parse(data["app_bar"]["app_bar_height"]);
    return getHeight;
  }
}
```

In the `load_app_style.dart` file i grab the value of `app_bar_heigt` from the `app_style.json`

in `app_style.json` i have key `app_bar_height` where i want to change the value manually to change the height of the App bar

```
{
  "app_bar":
  {
    "app_bar_height": 78
  },
  
}
```

But for some reason i get the error : `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'double'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the type to your `loadAppStyle` method. Since your method is `async` it returns a Future.

```
Future<double> loadAppStyle() async {
   ...
   return getHeight;
  }
```

Now your error should be

```
type 'Future<double>' is not a subtype of type 'double'
```

Since your method returns a `Future` you have to use [await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) to get the value.

```
loadAppStyle() // Future<double>
await loadAppStyle() // double
```

If you want to use a value of a `Future` inside a Widget, have a look at [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

For your case you could e.g. use the `FutureBuilder` to retrieve the height and then pass it to `AppBarBase`

```
FutureBuilder<double>(
  future: loadAppStyle(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData) {
      return AppBarBase(height: snapshot.data);
    } else {
      return const Center(child: CirclularProgressIndicator));
    }
  }
)
```

And change your `AppBarBase` to the following.

```
class AppBarBase extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  AppBarBase({
    Key? key,
    required this.height,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double height;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar();
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);
}
```

Comment: where do i put await?

Comment: I added an example. You cannot use await out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `loadAppStyle()` has no defined return type (dynamic) and it is marked as async (Future), hence the return type of this function is `Future<dynamic>`. `Size.fromHeight` function requires the `double` value, hence you get this error - the expected type is `double`, but `Future<dynamic>` was found here.

To resolve the type differences, you should set the return type of a function:

```
class LoadAppStyle {
  Future<double> loadAppStyle() async {
    String jsonData =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config/app_style.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    var getHeight = double.parse(data["app_bar"]["app_bar_height"]);
    return getHeight;
  }
}
```

Now, since your function is `async`, you must wait for your Future to finish and only then you could retrieve the `double` value. It would look something like this:

```
class AppBarBase extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  late double appBarHeight = await LoadAppStyle().loadAppStyle(); // Throws error

  AppBarBase({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar();
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(appBarHeight);
}
```

However, this throws an error since you cannot use the asynchronous code when initialising a value this way. What could be a better way to do this is to wait for this value somewhere outside of your widget and pass the result via the constructor:

```
class AppBarBase extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final double appBarHeight;

  AppBarBase({
    required this.appBarHeight,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar();
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(appBarHeight);
}
```

This way, you separate your UI code from the widget. Anyway, the way of keeping this UI-specific configuration inside the JSON file sounds way overengineered - consider just passing this value via constructor directly, like: `AppBarBase(appBarHeight: 78)`.

Comment: Its part of the usecase i need to change the appbar height via the json

Comment: Then everything should work this way, just you need to execute the `LoadAppStyle().loadAppStyle()` inside [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) outside of the AppBarBase.